# How to add boxed text at the bottom of the second column on the first page?

Tags: floats, two-column

I need to add some boxed text at the Bottom Right of the first page. If placed anywhere on the first page the box should appear at the Bottom Right of the first page. Please help me. I tried the following code

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
    \noindent\fbox{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                university Name \\
                Field of study  \\
                www.rt.de   \\
                Eone by: My name    \\
                E-Mail-Adresse: myemail \\
                supervisor1:    \\
                supervisor1:    \\
                supervisor1:    \\
            \end{tabular}
        }%
    }
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

> **Actual output**

[image]

> **Expected output**

[image]

Comment: Apart from the the technical problem, comparing with scientific journals of my field,  my expected format of author information is the first, not the second. I have not idea if there are any style recommendations about extra author information at the bottom of the page, somewhere, but you know ... when in Rome, do as the Romans.

Answer (score 4):

Just delay the placement of the code for you box until you've finished typesetting the first column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4] % First column material

\begin{table}[b]
  \begin{tabular}{| p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth} |}
    \hline
    University name:       \\
    Field of study         \\
    Website: www.cares.com \\
    Owned by: My name      \\
    Email address: myemail \\
    Supervisor 1:          \\
    Supervisor 2:          \\
    Supervisor 3:          \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[5-8] % Second column material

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this by banning all floats from the first column of the first page of your document by inserting `\suppressfloats` at the start of the document.
This command prohibits the placement of further floats in the current column and causes all floats declared here to be deferred to the second column.

Here is your MWE with just one line added to it.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\suppressfloats %% <- added

\begin{figure}[b]
    \noindent\fbox{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                university Name \\
                Field of study  \\
                www.rt.de   \\
                Eone by: My name    \\
                E-Mail-Adresse: myemail \\
                supervisor1:    \\
                supervisor1:    \\
                supervisor1:    \\
            \end{tabular}
        }%
    }
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you also have other floats on the first page you may need a different solution because their placement will of course be affected too. (This includes floats in the second column because floats can't appear out of order.)

Comment: The [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex-dev/base/source2e.pdf) actually says `\suppressfloats` “suppresses all further floats on the current page”, which is false in a two-column document.

Comment: As false as that `\newpage` or `\pagegreak`  will produce a change of page when it is in the first column. Confusing at first, until you end up seeing the two columns as two special narrow pages printed together.